# SSIS Configuration on SQL Server

Tags: ssis

I have scenario where I have several variables eg. sourceFilePath, sourceFileName and etc. I am storing the variables as a configurations in SQL Server Table. To store this configuration, we have to provide a connection (I have opted for OLEDB Connection).

When I am executing this from BIDS, it is working very fine and there are no issues at all.
I can change the sourceFilePath and sourceFileName from the Configuration table and the package is taking the changed path as well.

But the problem arrived when I have deployed the Package on SQL Server. I am not able to get the configuration values from table and it keeps on saying "Login failed from user.... Unable to load the configuration ...... ".

What can I do to avoide this situation?

Yes, I tried giving the password explicitly when scheduling the job but I can do the same for production server as it stores the password as a plain text.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: The normal approach here is to create a parameter to the package / project for the password and supply the necessary values at runtime. If you are using the 2012 version you can even create an environment to store typical or often-used parameter values. The parameter values are stored encrypted in the SSIS catalog is you mark them as sensitive.

Comment: Hi Brian,
Thanks for the comments. I have passing the values from configuration tables itself but at run time also, before getting the values from tables it seeks the connection which is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all. I just need to set ProtectionLevel property for my packages and the rest is done. Such a small thing and it was making me nuts...